# TSQL For Filter Experice From Range multiselect

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My Table contain Experience Field which is an integer . and my page contains a check box list like 0-3,3-7,7-9,9-12,12-15,15+ years and i have to filter this from table using select query i have tried `between` but it is not working when multiple fields selected  can any one help

my table structure is like

```
Name    Experience in year
----    ---------
a          1
b          2
c          3
d          5
e          2
f          1
```

My parameter for database is a varchar string

```
if we select 0-3years then  '0-3' 
if we select 3-6years then  '3-6' 
if we select both  then  '0-3,3-6' 
if we select 0-3years and 9-12years then '0-3,9-12'
```

Now i am sending Data in these format i dont know it is a good method please show me the better way

Comment: Show your query with `between`.  Also, show the layout (datatypes) for your columns.

Comment: experience is an `int` field my `between` query is not working properly when selecting both  0-3 years and 9-12 years scenario can you show me how it is done in these cases

Comment: But show us what your send from page to db. Specially when one or multiple check are selected.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i have updated the question please tell me if you needed anything. currently i am planning to pass value like this not fixed guide me if you have better idea

Comment: Where is the query that you've tried?

Comment: That is the problem. If you select both, can you modify your application to send `0-6` instead?  That would be the easy way. otherwise you will have to parse the string to get the values for the `between`  clausule.

Comment: @Biscuits I didnt actually tried i think about split the string and using `between` but it wont work when multiple fields are selected

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i thought about it but they can also select 0-3 year and 9-12 year only at that scenario it wont work rit actually not getting a proper logic how to do that

Comment: Ok, Good point. Then you should use that case as example instead :P, let me see what I can think.

Comment: I think you can use multiple BETWEEN filters, one for every checkbox, and OR them together. Alternatively, just make up a set of integers across all checkboxes and filter within that set using IN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a table checkRanges

```
CREATE TABLE checkRanges
    ([checkID] int, [name] varchar(8), [low] int, [upper] int);

INSERT INTO checkRanges
    ([checkID], [name], [low], [upper])
VALUES
    (1, '0-3', 0, 2),
    (2, '3-6', 3, 5),
    (4, '6-9', 6, 8),
    (8, '9-12', 9, 11),
    (16, '12+', 12, 999)
```

See how `checkID` are power of 2?

In your app if user select `3-6` and `9-12` you send `2+8 = 10` to your db. Also would be great if you create your check box using the db info.

In your db you do bitwise comparasion to select the right ranges.
Then perfom the between with each range.

```
WITH ranges as (
    SELECT *
    FROM checkRanges
    where checkID & 10 > 0
)
SELECT *
FROM users u
inner join ranges r
   on u.Experience between r.low and r.upper
```

See it all together [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49dff/5)
I include more users. You only have to change the clausule `where checkID & 10 > 0` to test other combination.

**NOTE:** 
I update the ranges. Change the upper value to `value - 1` because `between` is inclusive and could give duplicate results.

If want use old version you have to replace the `betwewen` in the join sentence to

```
u.Experience >= r.low and u.Experience *<* r.upper
```

Comment: I can do another version parsing string, but i think this is a cleaner more efficient version. Let me know if this work for you.

Comment: Thanks man ur solution worked  what is your other solution just curious if you dont mind..

Comment: I didn't make it. But involve, multiple string split, search between those result. Is more clumsy and hard to mantain If you want change ranges later. That was last resource if you couldnt make change in the app.